# How to create a personal git function, usable every time I launch Bash?

Tags: git, bash, function, github

I am developing a web site and I use git to update the site,
and I have two branch so it goes:

- git add .
- git commit "something"
- git push
- git checkout "prod"
- git merge --no-ff dev
- git push
- git checkout "dev"

I need a lazygit function which would looks like

```
function lazygit(){
    git add .
    git commit "$1"
    git push
    git checkout "prod"
    git merge --no-ff dev
    git push
    git checkout "dev"
}
```

And would be use like

```
lazygit( "CSS UPDATE" )
```

Now my question is, how can I save this function into file or whatsoever so I can use it anywhere ?

Thank's alot

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106606/6666

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to define a Git alias instead of a shell function.

Aliases are part of configuration, so let's look at the `gitconfig(7)` manual page (run `git help config` locally):

> `alias.*`
>
> Command aliases for the `git(1)` command wrapper - e.g. after defining `"alias.last = cat-file commit
>   HEAD"`, the invocation "git last" is equivalent to "git cat-file commit HEAD". To avoid confusion and
>   troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored. Arguments are split by
>   spaces, the usual shell quoting and escaping is supported. A quote pair or a backslash can be used to
>   quote them.
>
> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For
>   example, defining "alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD", the invocation "git new" is equivalent to
>   running the shell command "gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD". Note that shell commands will be executed from
>   the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.  GIT_PREFIX
>   is set as returned by running `git rev-parse --show-prefix` from the original current directory. See `git-rev-parse(1)`.

So you can do

```
$ git config --add alias.whatever '!set -eu; git add . &&
    git commit "$1" &&
    git push &&
    git checkout prod &&
    git merge --no-ff dev &&
    git push &&
    git checkout dev'
```

and then just

```
$ git whatever "commit message"
```

The `set -eu;` would make the whole thing crash unless you submit the required parameter.
Another approach would be to stick something like `test $# -gt 0 || exit 1;` there instead.

Comment: Thanks alot this helps and a better alternative.
But now when after commit even through I already put comment : as $1 = comment, I still have this https://imgur.com/a/L29RO and I just figure out how to get out of this box by entering :wq! ? is this becase I use alias ? or because I'm on windows ?

Comment: @JonelleAmio, not quite sure what happens, but I have two ideas. 1) Put the `shift` command after the `git commit "$1"` statement—to read `git commit "$1" && shift`—that should "consume" the argument passed by Git to the shell it invoked to process the script. 2) Add the `-x` option to the `set -eu` command: it will turn on "execution tracing" in the shell so that it prints each command it invokes prepended by a '+' character. That will show you the exact commands being run by the shell.

Comment: @JonelleAmio note that `git config` is a bit weird in that it has no `--set` option, so to "replace" your alias you might need to do `git config --unset alias.whatever` followed by `git config --add alias.whatever '!set …'`

Comment: @JonelleAmio, oh, and while we're at it, I should note that w/o any special options, the `git config` command operates *on the repository it's being run in.* This means your alias would only work when you're in the work tree of that very repository (and nowhere else). If you want it to become "global", pass the `--global` command-line option to `git config`: it will make that command to update your `~/.gitconfig` file. Also note that that file is merely an INI-style file, and you can just edit it by hand after the initial run of `git config --global --add alias.whatever …`

Comment: You're first idea is absolutely right, I checked git repository and haven't found any comments, seems that  `git commit "$1"`   isn't taken so wen I remove ad add the new alias with   `git commit "$1" && shift` well everything just look perfect. It's very weird because when I used this lines with function, I never had this problem... Anyway thanks alot !

Answer (score 5):

You can persist Bash functions, aliases, and settings in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` files (among other options). It's system-dependent, but most systems have a `~/.bashrc` and so that's generally what people will refer to.

I would also suggest chaining these commands with `&&`, so that if one fails the function stops, whereas your current function will keep running, ignoring any failures:

```
function lazygit(){
  git add . &&
    git commit "$1" &&
    git push &&
    git checkout prod &&
    git merge --no-ff dev &&
    git push &&
    git checkout dev
}
```

Also note that Bash doesn't use `()` when invoking functions, arguments are space-separated just like other shell commands. So you'd run:

```
$ lazygit "CSS UPDATE"
```